# Javascript failing xpath query, how to avoid it?

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, xpath

i am trying to parse the following code, but the javascript fails me ..

```
<span>
    <span class="contributorNameTrigger"><a href="/Nikolai-Shevchuk/e/B003Y0SWPS/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1" id="contributorNameTriggerB003Y0SWPSB0032JT11K" asin="B003Y0SWPSB0032JT11K">Nikolai Shevchuk</a>

<a href="#" asin="B003Y0SWPSB0032JT11K"><span style="margin-left:5px;" class="contributorChevron"><span class="swSprite s_chevron"></span></span></a></span>

   <span class="byLinePipe">(Author)</span>
</span>
```

and between is `<a href="#"` and `<span class="byLinePipe">` is the following javascript code

```
<input type="hidden" value="B003Y0SWPS" id="contributorASINB003Y0SWPSB0032JT11K">

      <span style="display:none"></span>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          amznJQ.onReady('bylinePopover', function () {});
      </script
```

i have submited the complete code on [codepad](http://codepad.org/7HUwqvjT)

the xpath query i am trying is..

```
$xpath_auth->query('//span/span[@class="contributorNameTrigger"]/text()
```

the script runs and fails me in getting the author name

> [Nikolai Shevchuk ]

, and returns blank
 
How can i avoid it ,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no `div` in the code you have given.

I would have thought just `//span[@class="contributorNameTrigger"]` would have been enough, then you can get the `textContent` of the node.